# Android job scheduler not persisted on reboot

Tags: android, service

I have implemented Job scheduler in my project and it works fine in the case if the app is in background or if the app is killed. But it is not working if the device is rebooted. I have included

```
     JobInfo.Builder mBuilder = new JobInfo.Builder(TASK_ID, mComponentName);
     mBuilder.setPersisted(true);
```

in my builder and

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in application manifest file.This is how I have added my service to manifest

```
     <service
        android:name="com.xxx.xxxx.service.MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Is there anything else to be included?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, and you probably already have the solution, but the issue likely was, that JobService caches the UUIDs of the apps that have the permission. You will need to reinstall your app and it is gonna be alright.

Source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5d34605/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java

Answer (score -2):

You need to call the setPersisted(boolean isPersisted) method.

You can find it in the doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)

Comment: already called `setPersisted` ,Don't you read question properly?