# Scheduling persisted periodic job in Android

Tags: android

I want to schedule persisted periodic job which won't depend on system reboot. What is the best place to schedule the job? I think that putting scheduling into `BOOT_COMPLETED` Broadcast receiver will "reschedule" the job and it'll lead to unexpected behaviour (at least it's redundant, no?). May be `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` receiver?

Thanks for any ideas.

**EDIT**

I know this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084205/3974530

But I want PERSISTED job. I'm afraid of situation like: you have a periodic job which is running every 24 hours. And, for example, every 4 hours you reboot your device. So after each reboot the job will be rescheduled and... Your job will never be executed because the timer has been reset. Am I right?

The question is about **JobScheduler** only!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android job scheduler not persisted on reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084112/android-job-scheduler-not-persisted-on-reboot)

Comment: wherever you put code to `reschedule` just make sure that you cancel the current job if exists. Then it won't lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Please check:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42084205/3974530

Comment: Guys, please check my question after edit

Answer (score -1):

`BOOT_COMPLETED` is the first correct step in this.

You do it this way:

First, in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

You create a service that extends `GcmTaskService`.
Here you make a public static method setupGcmTasks and you MUST `@override onInitializeTasks`. This callback is invoked when your app gets updated.

Key here is, that you set `updateCurrent(true)` for the task, so it replaces the existing one, making things much easier for you (rescheduling, etc).

```
public class MyTaskService extends GcmTaskService {

public static void setupGcmTasks(@NonNull Context context) {
    GcmNetworkManager networkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(context);

    Task task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()... // create your task
        .setTag(YOUR_TASK_TAG)
        .setUpdateCurrent(true)
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build();

    networkManager.schedule(task);
}

@Override
public void onInitializeTasks() {
    super.onInitializeTasks();
    setupGcmTasks(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int onRunTask(TaskParams taskParams) {
    try {
        switch (taskParams.getTag()) {
            case YOUR_TASK_TAG:
                // Do your stuff
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log it
    }

    return GcmNetworkManager.RESULT_SUCCESS;
}
}
```

And finally, a `BroadcastReceiver` for device boots

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null &&
        intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        myTaskService.setupGcmTasks(context); // Call the static of your service
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean scheduling with JobScheduler. I understand that I can cancel any jobs after reboot and reschedule it, but look at my question again, please. I want to avoid situation above.

Comment: I do not recommend using JobScheduler (any more). Why not save a setting when you schedule your task containing the next time when it shall run. When you receive a boot complete you simply calculate the next run time and schedule accordingly. whenever the task fires, reschedule at the default interval.